# Why doesn't nitric acid have a positive charge?

Tags: acid-base, covalent-compounds

From the diagrams I've seen $\ce{HNO3}$ has a dative covalent bond so why doesn't it have a positive charge?

Comment: Do you mean an overall positive change or a positive charge on the nitrogen atom?

Comment: Wouldn't a positive charge on the nitrogen cause an overall charge on the molecule?

Comment: Not necessarily, see the nitro group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One side of the $\ce{HNO3}$ molecule *does* have a positive charge, but this is neutralized by the negative charge resulting from the Oxygen atom with only one bond to the nitrogen. These charges cancel leaving an overall neutral molecule.

[image: nitric acid]